# Getting views of a custom view in android

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, custom-view

Well I have a listview with an OnItemClickListener on it, each item of listview is a customview with two textviews, I want to get text of first textview when an item is clicked, So how can I do that? when an item is clicked I can just get the view that is clicked but how can I get textview on this customview?

Comment: Can you check if there is a way to get the items inside the custom view? something like items[0] or a function that returns the item given an index

Comment: I tried the first answer below and it works I did not know that there exist such a simple way! @Víctor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traverse that view's hierarchy:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.first_text_view);
```

`clickedView` is provided to you by `OnItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                textFromFirstView = yourArray.get(position).getTextFromFirst();
            }
        });
```

whre getTextFromFirst() is getter for your textview for example

Comment: This is a working solution for me. Just add the onItemClickListener and position will tell you which item is clicked. Setting this to 0 you can get always the first item. GetTextFromThis() must be implemented in the CustomListView-Item!

Comment: I think I did not understand your solution, position gives the position of item on the list view but I want to get a textview on a item of listview.